# Categorical Regression with Centered Levels

Tags: r, linear-regression, categorical-data

R's standard way of doing regression on categorical variables is to select one factor level as a reference level and constraining the effect of that level to be zero. Instead of constraining a single level effect to be zero, I'd like to constrain the *sum* of the coefficients to be zero.

I can hack together coefficient estimates for this manually after fitting the model the standard way:

```
x <- lm(data = mtcars, mpg ~ factor(cyl))
z <- c(coef(x), "factor(cyl)4" = 0)
y <- mean(z[-1])
z[-1] <- z[-1] - y
z[1] <- z[1] + y
z
## (Intercept) factor(cyl)6 factor(cyl)8 factor(cyl)4 
##  20.5021645   -0.7593074   -5.4021645    6.1614719
```

But that leaves me without standard error estimates for the former reference level that I just added as an explicit effect, and I need to have those as well.

I did some searching and found the `constrasts` functions, and tried

```
lm(data = mtcars, mpg ~ C(factor(cyl), contr = contr.sum))
```

but this still only produces two effect estimates. Is there a way to change which constraint R uses for linear regression on categorical variables properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've figured it out. Using `contrasts` actually is the right way to go about it, you just need to do a little work to get the results into a convenient looking form. Here's the fit:

```
fit <- lm(data = mtcars, mpg ~ C(factor(cyl), contr = contr.sum))
```

Then the matrix `cs <- contr.sum(factor(cyl))` is used to get the effect estimates and the standard error.

The effect estimates just come from multiplying the contrast matrix by the effect estimates `lm` spits out, like so:

```
cs %*% coef(fit)[-1]
```

The standard error can be calculated using the contrast matrix and the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients, like so:

```
diag(cs %*% vcov(fit)[-1,-1] %*% t(cs))
```